# How can I avoid xlabel overlapping in graphviz?

Tags: r, graphviz, dot

I'm trying to recreate the following diagram using graphviz (or any other graphing tool that involves coding for the nodes and edges).

[image: Example of a Hasse diagram]

To do so, I used the following code but it doesn't yield a correct output because the labels are overlapping and cannot be positionned specifically. Is there a way of avoiding labels overlapping ?

```
digraph G {
    edge [arrowhead="none"];
    node [shape="point"];
    U [xlabel="U 1,1"]; 
    S [xlabel="S 3,2"];
    P [xlabel="P 5,4"];
    E [xlabel="E 15,8"];
    U -> {S, P}; {S, P} -> E;
}
```

[image: Failed attempt in graphviz]

Answer (score 0):

xlabels are hard (impossible?) to wrangle.
Instead, this uses HTML-like nodes, ports & a bullet glyph

```
graph G {
    graph [splines=false nodesep=.95]
    edge  [headclip=false tailclip=false];
    node  [shape="plain"] 
    U [label=<<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" cellborder="0">
       <tr><td>U 1,1</td></tr>
       <tr><td port="p1">&#9679;</td></tr></table>>]; 
    S [label=<<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" cellborder="0">
       <tr><td>S 3,2</td><td port="p1">&#9679;</td></tr></table>>];
    P [label=<<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" cellborder="0">
       <tr><td port="p1">&#9679;</td><td>P 5,4</td></tr></table>>];
    E [label=<<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" cellborder="0">
       <tr><td port="p1">&#9679;</td></tr>
       <tr><td>E 15,8</td></tr></table>>];

    U:p1:c -- S:p1:c
    U:p1:c -- P:p1:c
    S:p1:c -- E:p1:c
    P:p1:c -- E:p1:c
}
```

Giving:
[image]